# _payload.json is not generated by `nuxi generate` when deploying nuxt-content website

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, pinia, nuxt-content

I use nuxt 3, pinia and nuxt-content to build my blog and everything works well with dev server (`nuxi dev`). However, when I want to deploy it as a static website, I run `nuxi generate` and find that my posts are not rendered and chrome dev console shows:

[image: error image]

If I understand correctly, my posts data is stored in `_payload.json`, which was not generated by `nuxi generate`. Does anyone know what causes this error? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you solved this problem? @why